# C# Forms - I need a way to get alerted that a feed has been updated

Tags: c#, .net, forms, desktop, websub

I'm not totally sure this is possible but I need something like PubSubHubbub (websub) that can ping a C# .net forms desktop application. Can I setup a way to hear the ping from PubSubHubbub or similar?

I'm not exactly sure how it all works but I need in the end a way to know when a CAP Feed has been updated without having to parse it every few minutes. I want updates as soon as the page changes.

This is for a National Weather Alerts project.

Comment: You might consider something like Signal R, have you looked into it? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr

Comment: Never heard of it. But it appears to be for asp .net. I'm still reading up on it but if that is the case that won't work. It needs to be for a .net desktop forms application.

Comment: PubSub patterns work by subscribing to a queue or similar mechanism, when a message is added you will receive it an can perform an action on it. There are many out  there. RabbitMQ, MSMQ to name a couple more. Your application can publish a message in a queue and the client will be listening. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/publisher-subscriber

Comment: I do not own the server that the feed is on. The feed is hosted on https://alert-hub.appspot.com/

Comment: here is a good example - You should be able to follow the code here: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1229912/Push-Notification-PubSubHubBub-from-Youtube-to-Csh

Comment: @osoclever Thank you! I'll look into it tomorrow and get back to you. It looks promising. I did see that page but haven't had the time to test it yet.